# RegEx to compare any character between 59 tabs

Tags: regex, notepad++

I recently received a tab separated file that has 60 fields. Each field can have any character in it. The export I received also has linefeeds and carriage returns in some of the fields. This is causing the tab separated file to not import correctly. Is there a way to remove linebreaks and carriage returns if the line does not have 59 tabs on it? There may or may not be data between each tab.

[Sample File](http://tempsend.com/4E46AB9FA3)

Line 3,4,5 is the issue I'm trying to fix.

Comment: What language are you going to use, and can you give a few example lines? Specifically you should provide sample input, what to match, and sample output. (Also worth nothing that regex is just for matching; it doesn't do the transformation for you.)

Comment: I would probably read the file line by line, check if the line has 59 tabs and then join with the next line if it doesn't. Seems like the simplest solution. In addition, tsv's should have quotes around any fields that have linebreaks e.t.c. inside so double check you are using the correct quote character when you're reading it.

Comment: I'm using notepad++. I'm planning on just finding and replacing unless  it is overly complicated.

Comment: Please, add more details, a sample of your file and as Mathletics said edit your post by adding a tag with your language

Comment: @Jacob Notepad++ doesn't have a perfect regex engine.

Comment: @abc123 I thought Notepad++ had the full PCRE. What's imperfect about it?

Comment: @Dane it doesn't like line wraps

Comment: @Mike The file is 86,000+ lines.

Comment: @Jacob I meant read with a programming language, it will take milliseconds. :)

Comment: @Jacob is the problem you have related to windows carriage return?

Comment: Something based on replacing `^(([^\r\n\t]*\t){0,58})([^\r\n\t]*)\r\n` with `\1\3` may work, provided tab characters are not allowed within string quotes. It may be safer to search for the expression and choose manually whether to make the replacements.

Comment: @abc123 I created a chat room to find out more about Notepad++, PCRE, and line-wraps. I'd like to understand what limitation you're talking about, since I rely on N++ and its PCRE pretty heavily.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for the sample input! It works with the steps I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: I'm assuming that there are no tabs within a column's data. If there is, then you need something far more capable that what I have here.

The following works with the [sample input provided](http://tempsend.com/4E46AB9FA3):

First, replace all of the line breaks with a character that doesn't occur anywhere in your file. You can even use characters that you can't type with your keyboard.

Find what: `(\r\n?|\n)`

Replace with: `\xB6`

Then, match your 60-field rows and give them line-breaks (I'm going with Windows-style):

Find what: `^(([^\t]*\t){59}[^\t\xB6]*)\xB6`

Replace with: `$1\r\n`

I'm making one huge assumption here: that column 60 never contains a line break. If this is false, then you're going to have some of column 60's data ending up in column 1 of the next record.

Now, if you don't like that paragraph symbol showing up in your data, you can either purge it or replace it with whatever you like:

Find what: `\xB6`

Replace with:

Explanation of matching patterns:

`(\r\n?|\n)` matches any of the three kinds of line breaks, which are single `\r`, a single `\n`, or the Windows-style `\r\n`. [Wikipedia has a whole article about this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

See http://regex101.com/r/iB6fK9 to explore the `^(([^\t]*\t){59}[^\t\xB6]*)\xB6` pattern.

- I'm matching the beginning of the line with `^` at the start.
- I have a group of zero or more characters that are not a tab, followed by a tab, that I match exactly 59 times with `([^\t]*\t){59}`. That gets us the first 59 tab-separated columns. Only column 59 is captured by this group.
- For column 60, I match zero or more characters that are neither a tab nor our special character with `[^\t\xB6]*`.
- I capture the 60 columns with parentheses, but I leave our special character outside of the captured group so that it gets replaced with the `\r\n` that we insert with the `$1\r\n` replacement.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you want to remove the windows `\r\n` from your file, to do this you can use replace dialog `ctrl+h`.

On the `Search Mode` select `Extended (\n, \r,...`, then on the "Find What" look for `\r\n` and in "Replace" leave it empty (or replace it with what you want).

Comment: The question asks how to replace _if it's not a `\n` with 59 `\t`'s before it_.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

Find what: `^((?:[^\t]*\t[^\t]*){1,58})[\r\n]+`
Replace with: `$1`

This will replace line break with nothing if there are less than 59 occurrence of `\t` character in a line.

Comment: This is a simpler process than I offered. Don't you mean `^(([^\t]*\t){1,58}[^\t]*)[\r\n]+` however?

Comment: @Dane: Of course it's tabulation. I don't know where I get the pipe character ???

Comment: So, you've still got one pipe in there, plus you're requiring that there be at least two characters of data in every field, when the asker stated that fields can be null. Also, couldn't this cause some pretty weird behavior depending on the order of replacement, since it might add a partial to the following complete row?